# Sign change of a polynomial between roots

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with $n$ distinct real roots. Label the roots of $p(x)$ as $x_1, x_2, ...,x_n,$ such that $x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n$. Suppose that $p(x)$ has a root that is also a stationary point, i.e. $\exists \ i \in \{1,2, ... ,n\}$ such that $p(x_i) = p'(x_i)=0$. Is it then true that the sign of $p(x)$ over the interval $\left(x_{i-1},x_i\right)$ is the same as the sign of $p(x)$ over $\left(x_{i},x_{i+1}\right)?$ Intuitively this seems true, but does a rigorous proof for this exist?

*Edit:* As commented in one of the answers, this claim is not always true. In particular, if one has the polynomial $p(x)=x^3(x-1)(x+1)$, where the root $x=0$ is a point of inflection, then there is a sign change. Thus a root which is a stationary point does not imply that there is a sign change. However, would the converse be true then? If there is no sign change at a root, does that mean that the root is a stationary point?

Comment: By writing $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n$, you're suggesting that all of the real roots are distinct in which case $p(x_i)=p'(x_i)=0$ cannot occur.

Comment: @bjorn93 valid point,maybe OP is suggesting as $n$ *distinct* real roots

Comment: Oh, I actually did not realize that. So essentially the point is, if $p(x)$ has n distinct real roots, all of which are simple roots (with multiplicity 1), then the case $p(x_i)=p'(x_i)=0$ cannot occur? Why is that the case then?

Comment: Oh, is it because if $\alpha$ is a root of multiplicity $k$ of $p(x)$, then it is also a root of multiplicity $k-1$ of $p'(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^3(x-1)(x+1)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Hmm, so I plotted the graph out and realised that this polynomial has a point of inflection at $x=0$. So would it be right if I instead claimed that either a minimum or maximum point at a root would mean there is no sign change, but an inflection point at a root could imply a sign change?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case of a double root at $x_i$, the sign does not change. This happen for each root which is two-fold, four-fold and so on.
The condition $p(x_i)=p'(x_i)=0$ and $p''(x_i)\ne 0$ means that the root $x_i$ is two-fold.

Comment: So, in other words, there is no sign change for roots of even multiplicity? Why is that so? For that matter, does $p(x_i)=p'(x_i)=0$ necessarily imply the root is of even multiplicity then?